# AttributeError: 'QWheelEvent' object has no attribute 'delta'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a simple GUI using pyqt5. It runs fine, but when I open it and try to use the mouse's wheel, it crashes with the following error:

> AttributeError: 'QWheelEvent' object has no attribute 'delta'.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(View, self).__init__()

        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.initScene(5)

    def initScene(self,h):     

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        #self.setSceneRect(0, 100, 1400, 700)  #this controls where the scene begins relative to the window
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.setGeometry(0,0,900,700)
        #self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 2607, 700)


        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1,wspace=0, hspace=0)
        axes1 = self.figure.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
        axes2 = self.figure.add_subplot(3, 1, 2)
        axes3 = self.figure.add_subplot(3, 1, 3)
        axes1.yaxis.set_ticks([5,6])
        axes1.set_yticklabels([5,6])
        #axes.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')
        axes1.yaxis.set_tick_params(color='red',labelcolor='red',direction='in',labelright = 'on',labelleft='off')
        axes1.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10), np.linspace(0,10,10))
        axes2.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10), np.linspace(0,10,10))
        axes3.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10), np.linspace(0,10,10))
        axes1.spines['bottom'].set_color('red')
        axes2.spines['top'].set_color('red')
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addWidget(self.canvas)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 1424, 750) #the first two arguments control where the window will appear on the screen, the next

        self.view = View()
        self.view.setGeometry(0,0,1400,700)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Other details which might be relevant: I saved the code as a .py file and I run it from the 'Anaconda Prompt' command line.

If I don't connect the mouse click event to anything, then it doesn't crash, so I can't understand why it crashes I when I use the mouse's wheel (even if not connected to anything).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using PyQt5 but then you import the matplotlib backend for PyQt4, so I guess this is where the error comes from.

Qt4 had a `delta` attribute in the class `QWheelEvent` but now in Qt5 this has been replaced by two different properties `angleDelta` and `pixelDelta` so that's why you get the error.

To solve it simply replace your import as follows (replace the 4 for a 5):

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

**References**

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qwheelevent.html